# onplay, onpause event of a Soundcloud oembed widget

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I'm trying to use the souncloud javascript api to trigger an onplay and onpause call back of an oembeded widget. So basically I'm using SC.oembed to create/display the widget in a div, and then i thought to use SC.stream to control the soundmanager 2 options, but this doesn't seem possible.

All I want to do is call a function when someone presses play on the widget, and when someone presses pause.

What is the best way to achieve this result?

**UPDATE**
Here's a code snippet

```
        //set up soundcloud gallery
        SC.initialize({
          client_id: 'MY_CLIENT_ID'
        });

        SC.get('/users/MY_USER/tracks', function(tracks) {
            $('#tracks_holder').addClass('scrollY').empty()
            for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
              console.log(tracks[i].title);
              var newTrack = $('<div class="scTrack"></div>')[0];
              SC.oEmbed(tracks[i].permalink_url, {maxheight:"200px"}, newTrack);
            $('#tracks_holder').append(newTrack);
            }
        });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your code and what documentation are you using to do this?

Comment: Added the code snippet. I want to load multiple tracks dynamically and apply a callback on each individual oembed widget. Documentation I was using https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#embedding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great example **[HERE](https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/html5-widget-api)**. SC allows you to attach handlers to many events, as is in the docs **[HERE](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget#events)**

```
  (function(){
    var widgetIframe = document.getElementById('sc-widget'),
        widget       = SC.Widget(widgetIframe);

    widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {
      widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, function() {
        // get information about currently playing sound
        widget.getCurrentSound(function(currentSound) {
          console.log('sound ' + currentSound.get('') + 'began to play');
        });
      });
      // get current level of volume
      widget.getVolume(function(volume) {
        console.log('current volume value is ' + volume);
      });
      // set new volume level
      widget.setVolume(50);
      // get the value of the current position
    });

  }());
```

Audio related events:

1. SC.Widget.Events.LOAD_PROGRESS — fired periodically while the sound is loading.
2. SC.Widget.Events.PLAY_PROGRESS — fired periodically while the sound is playing.
3. SC.Widget.Events.PLAY — fired when the sound begins to play.
4. SC.Widget.Events.PAUSE — fired when the sound pauses.
5. SC.Widget.Events.FINISH — fired when the sound finishes.
6. SC.Widget.Events.SEEK — fired when the user seeks.

Comment: awesome! glad to help. would you mind selecting as correct, in that case?\